# Which is best practice to add custom css to SharePoint site?

Tags: 2013, css

Foll. are approaches I am aware off. Please add if there are any more, and let me know which is the best approach.

1. Go to SharePoint designer. Take backup of existing master page. Create new master page and just before the head tag ends, and after the `SharePoint:CssLink control` add the following line:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style Library/INSERT_PATH.css" />
   ```
2. Use code like following on master page after the `<SharePoint:CssRegistration` of the core css file:

`<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="/_layouts/15/SPS.CssModule/Styles/newcssfile.css" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />`

3. Like below code:

   < asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
         < style>
     /* insert css here */
         < / style>
       < /asp:Content>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach is the best way to add a custom css file to a master page. Backing up master page and then creating a custom master page, adding custom CSS file to Style Library and then adding external CSS link under `<head>` tag. These steps are the most recommended and considered as best approach. Just make sure to add the external css link just above the content place holder named `PlaceHolderAdditonalPageHead`.

What @Ram has mentioned is also one of the approach but not a best practice as it has some restrictions. Adding CSS reference in Site Settings > Master Page, limits you to customize only those IDs and classes that are included on the pages by SharePoint.

Comment: Why above the content place holder named PlaceHolderAdditonalPageHead? Can I place it within this holder?

Comment: Why above the content place holder named PlaceHolderAdditonalPageHead? Can I place it within this holder?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use the 'Alternate CSS URL' for adding custom CSS to a SharePoint Site.

Go to Site Settings -> Master Page -> 'Alternate CSS Url'. Browse for the custom CSS file and save it. This adds the CSS to the site without any change to the master page.